# How can I test async react redux call

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, jestjs

I'm trying to test login user actions, but I always get the empty array for my `store.getActions()`. How can I test login user function, to get action type `SET_USER` if it is success or ERROR if not. Here is my code for auth actions

```
export const loginUser = (user) => dispatch => {
axios
    .post('http://localhost:5000/users/login', user)
    .then(res => {

        dispatch({
            type: 'SET_USER',
            payload: res.data
        })
    })
    .catch(err => 
        dispatch({
            type: 'ERROR',
            payload: err.response
          })
    );
};
```

and here for auth actions test

```
import { loginUser } from '../../actions/authActions';

import configureMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = configureMockStore(middlewares);

describe('Auth actions', () => {
    const user = {
        email: 'user@test.com',
        password: '123456',
    }

    let store;
    beforeEach(() => {
      store = mockStore();
    });

    it('should login user', () => {
        store.dispatch(loginUser())
       console.log(store.getActions())
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like dispatch needs to be passed first to create a function that accepts a user and responds using the dispatch:

```
// ---- authActions.js ----
import axios from 'axios';

export const loginUser = dispatch => user => {
  axios
      .post('http://localhost:5000/users/login', user)
      .then(res => {

          dispatch({
              type: 'SET_USER',
              payload: res.data
          })
      })
      .catch(err => 
          dispatch({
              type: 'ERROR',
              payload: err.response
            })
      );
  };
```

To test it you need to mock `axios.post()` and create a mock to pass as `dispatch`.  You will need to make the test functions `async` and pause them to let the callbacks execute.  All together the test looks like this:

```
// ---- authActions.test.js ----
import axios from 'axios';
import { loginUser } from '../../actions/authActions';

describe('Auth actions', () => {

  const user = {
    email: 'user@test.com',
    password: '123456',
  }

  let postMock;
  let dispatchMock;

  beforeEach(() => {
    postMock = jest.spyOn(axios, 'post');
    postMock.mockImplementation((url, u) => {
      if (u === user) {
        return Promise.resolve({ data: 'mocked response' });
      }
      else {
        return Promise.reject({ response: 'login failed' });
      }
    });
    dispatchMock = jest.fn();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    postMock.mockRestore();
  });

  it('should login user', async () => {
    loginUser(dispatchMock)(user);
    // Pause the synchronous test here to let the event loop cycle
    await Promise.resolve();

    expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      type: 'SET_USER',
      payload: 'mocked response'
    });
  });

  it('should return error', async () => {
    loginUser(dispatchMock)({ email: 'something', password: 'invalid' });
    // Allow two event loop cycles for the catch to execute
    await Promise.resolve().then();

    expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(dispatchMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({
      type: 'ERROR',
      payload: 'login failed'
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but I alway get ERROR action type, with payload of undefined.

Comment: @Dalies I just realized you should probably be passing `dispatch` first so I've updated my answer with the recommended code change and a functioning test

Comment: @Dalies friendly reminder to upvote and mark as accepted if an answer provides the info you need.  If you have any further questions let us know